# how to set the selected value in the drop down list populated with ViewData in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to MVC, please help me to set the selected value in drop down list populated using View Data. I have gone through so many solutions but every solutions deals with selecting value for single drop down. I have same drop down listed using the `foreach` loop. Setting selected value for each dropdown in that `foreach` loop. 
My code is shown below.

[In view]

```
int i = 0;

foreach (var item in Model.Select((x, j) => new { Data = x, Index = j + 1 })) {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.Data.CategoryID,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["categories"], new { @id = "category" + i })
    i++;
}
```

[in controller]

```
SelectList selectList = new SelectList((IEnumerable<Category>)ConvertCategoryToList(dt1), "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
ViewData["categories"] = selectList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot missing from your sample (e.g.what a category looks like, what the Edit actions look like, what is `dt1`, what the model is you pass to the view etc), but I will try based on what is shown.

### Problem 1: Can't use foreach in binding

You can't use a `foreach` with a collection of form items. The items have no way of knowing which individual element to bind with (when they are sent back to the server they need more information to make each entry unique).

**Solution:**

It only knows how to bind if you use indexing (e.g. using `for (int i=0; < count; i++){ @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>item[i]...`)

### Problem 2: Selected values only can come from SelectList!

This is the most irritating feature of `DropDownListFor` and appears to be a bug. It will not take the current selected value from the bound data. It will only take a current value from a SelectList, which means **you need a unique SelectList for every dropdown**.

**Solution:**

Create a unique `SelectList` in the view, per drop down required, with the item value as the current selection.

With some faking of your data, I got the following working:

## Example

### Controller:

Only store the list of items for the SelectList in the ViewBag:

```
ViewData["categories"] = ConvertCategoryToList(dt1);
```

### View:

**1. You need to pass a `List` and not an `IEnumerable` as IEnumerable cannot be indexed.**

```
@model List<MyApplication.Item>
```

**2. Create a SelectList for each dropdown**

```
SelectList newSelectList = new SelectList((IEnumerable<MyApplication.Category>)ViewData["categories"], "CategoryID", "CategoryName", Model[i].Id);
```

**3. Use the indexing method for addressing your items in the collection.**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[i].Id, newSelectList, "Select an item")
```

### Problem 3: What data to pass?

The other issue with your code, as-it-stands, is what to pass back and forth to/from the edit view? At the moment I would guess (from the variable name *dt1*) you are passing a `DataTable`(?). You will need to be very explicit about the data you are using in order to get a clean solution to this one. I would suggest posting a second question with all your code and Razor view HTML.

If you need to see more of my sample code (below), please post your own code so I can make them consistent.

### Full dummy controller code below

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public List<Category> dt1 { get; set; }

    public TestController()
    {
        this.dt1 = new List<Category>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            this.dt1.Add(new Category() { CategoryId = i, CategoryName = string.Format("Category {0}", i) });
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        //SelectList selectList = new SelectList((IEnumerable<Category>)ConvertCategoryToList(dt1), "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
        ViewData["categories"] = ConvertCategoryToList(dt1);

        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        items.Add(new Item(){Id = 1});
        items.Add(new Item(){Id = 2});
        items.Add(new Item(){Id = 3});
        items.Add(new Item(){Id = 4});
        items.Add(new Item(){Id = 5});

        return View(items);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection form)
    {
        // Turn form submission back into a compatible view model
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        foreach (string key in form.Keys)
        {
            string val = form[key];
            items.Add(new Item() { Id = int.Parse(val) });
        }
        // Recreate the select list
       ViewData["categories"] = ConvertCategoryToList(dt1);

        return View(items);
    }

    List<Category> ConvertCategoryToList(IEnumerable<Category> dt)
    {
        return dt.ToList();
    }
}
```

*Note: The post version of Edit simply recreates the list of data (using the selected values posted back) and returns to the Edit view. This is just for testing.*

### Screen shot

[image]

### Dummy category class

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

### Full test View

```
@model List<MyApplication.Item>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        SelectList newSelectList = new SelectList((IEnumerable<MyApplication.Category>)ViewData["categories"], "CategoryID", "CategoryName", Model[i].Id);
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[i].Id, newSelectList, "Select an item")
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Comment: TrueBlueAussie thanks for your comment...........SelectList newSelectList = new SelectList((IEnumerable<MyApplication.Category>)ViewData["categories"], "CategoryID", "CategoryName", Model[i].Id);
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model[i].Id, newSelectList, "Select an item").......................From the above line i got the idea to the anwer for my question.................@Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.Data.CategoryID, new SelectList((IEnumerable<MVCWorkStatusManager.Models.Category>)ViewData["categories"], "CategoryID", "CategoryName", item.Data.CategoryID), new { @id = "category" })